# Is there a symbol for 'a bit smaller than'?

Tags: algebra

Im looking for a sign that is the reciprocal of '$\ll$'.

Where $a\ll b$ means that $a$ is very much smaller than $b$ (and perhaps may be neglected), im looking for a sign that expresses that $a$ is only a bit less than $b$.
This symbol should not be $\sim$, as this would include 'a bit greater than' as well

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably better posted on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In this situation, you might introduce a symbol and provide its intended meaning for your context; a possible choice for the symbol is **\lesssim**, which is rendered as $\lesssim$ in TeX.

Comment: Could you provide some context for when and how you would like to use this symbol? As some of the answers below show, it is not clear what exactly you mean.

Comment: The "reciprocal of $\ll$" seems a weird way to describe whatever you want to describe. The opposite from $\ll$ makes sense to me, but means something probably different from what you want ("not much smaller or greater than").

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there is, largely because the concept is ill-defined:  Is 5 "a bit less than" 6?  Is 995 "a bit less than" 996?  Is the important point here the absolute difference $|x-y|$, or the relative difference $\frac{|x-y|}{y}$?

Of course, having said that, it has to be acknowledged that the exact same criticism could be laid against the notation $x<<y$, which I have always been uncomfortable with for the same reason.  Just how much smaller than $y$ does $x$ need to be?  But despite this, people seem to be generally comfortable with writing $x<<y$, and letting context clarify its meaning.

So here are two proposals:

1. You could, as Benjamin Dickman suggests in comments, use the symbol $\lesssim$.  It does not have a "standard" meaning, but you could establish a local convention that it means "less than but approximately equal to".  As long as you establish (in whatever context you are using the symbol) what it means *in that context* it would seem to serve your purpose well.
2. A second option is to appropriate the existing usage of $<<$ as follows:  To say that "$x$ is a little bit less than $y$" you could write either $y-x<<1$ (if what you are trying to say is that $y$ is a bit less than $x$ in *absolute terms*), or $y-x<<y$ (if what you are trying to say is that $y$ is a bit less than $x$ *relative to the scale of $y$*).  Either of those seem to capture well the sense you are looking for, provided you have already established a contextual convention that the notation $a<<b$ is only used when both $a$ and $b$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you don't introduce new symbols; it adds too much to cognitive load. Instead you could say $b-\epsilon< a < b$ for some $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: That's equivalent to just saying $a < b$, though, because one can just take $\epsilon = b - a + 1$, for instance.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is usually interpreted to be small.

Comment: @DanielHast:  I think that by 'some', he meant $\varepsilon$ to be predetermined, even though it looks like a quantifier.  At least that's what my common sense suggests.  Maybe there's one relation $<_\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon$!  (Actually, 'one' might read better as 'a (separate)'.  Confusion abounds.)

Comment: @Adam: I don't think the habit of making hidden assumptions should be encouraged. There is nothing about the letter "$\epsilon$" that inherently means "a small number"; if we want it to be small, we should say so, and say what we mean by "small". It's fine, of course, to specify some small number $\epsilon$ and then say $b - \epsilon < a < b$; if that's what you meant, I have no objection to it.

Comment: @DanielHast  This is true, but I recall someone giving the following definition of continuity:  a function $\epsilon$ is continuous at $y = \delta$ if for every $f>0$ there is a $g>0$ such that $|\delta - \psi|<g$ implies $|\epsilon(\delta) - \epsilon(\psi)|<f$.  Clearly choice of symbols matter.  This also illustrates some of the difficulty a new student of mathematics, who is not encultured to the "usual" meaning of symbols, might have.

Comment: My thought was just to write $a=b-\varepsilon$. I would think that indicates '$a$ is a bit smaller than $b$' without needing to specify precisely what that means.

Answer (score 0):

As *mweiss* said, it's ill-defined, but if you make it precise then you would probably find that you want to say "$a \nearrow b$ as $x \to c$", where $x$ and $c$ are some expressions that you have in mind but didn't specify. This parallels "$\frac{a}{b} \to 0$ as $x \to c$" or "$a \in o(b)$ as $x \to c$" to precisely express "$a \ll b$" with all the necessary context.

Comment: I think it's interesting that you naturally interpreted the context as one in which $a$ and $b$ are varying quantities, whereas I interpreted them as constants.

Comment: @mweiss: If they are just constants, then as you already said in your answer it's ill-defined. We say for example that central limit theorem works well for sample size $n \gg 1$, but how well is well? Of course, the better you want the approximation, the larger you need $n$ to be. That's equivalent to the "varying quantities conception". I don't see what context has $a,b$ as constants where it makes much sense to talk about "slightly less".